# non-numeric argument to binary operator

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm attempting to create my first function in R. The function should take in a data frame, x-series from data frame, y-series from data frame, and plot a scatter plot.  Seems simple enough, but I run into trouble when I attempt to check for an optional boolean argument.

#### R Script

```
plotScatterChart <- function(data,x,y,scale=y,line=FALSE) {

    require(ggplot2)
    data$x <- as.numeric(x)
    data$y <- as.numeric(y)

    plot <- ggplot(data, aes(x, y)) + 
            geom_point() +  # aes(alpha=0.3,color=scale)
            #scale_color_gradient(high="red")

    if(line) {
        plot <- plot + geom_smooth(method="lm") 
    }

    ggsave(file="plot.svg", plot=plot, height=10, width=10)

    return(plot)
}

plotScatterChart(data=iris,x=iris$Petal.Length,y=iris$Petal.Width,line=TRUE)
```

#### Error

```
non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

#### Extra

Other suggestions for improving this function are welcome.

Comment: Trailing plus sign: `geom_point() +`

Comment: Yep, that was a major derp on my part.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The error is because of the trailing `+` after `geom_point()`.  Remove that and it should work.

Answer (score 20):

Christopher's answer is perfectly correct. Let me add that `ggplot` also seems to accept lists:

```
plot <- ggplot(data, aes(x, y)) +
  list(
    geom_point(),
    aes(alpha=0.3,color=scale),
    scale_color_gradient(high="red"),
    NULL
  )
```

Unfortunately, unlike Python where you can write `[1, 2, 3, ]`, the construct `list(1, 2, 3, )` produces an error in R. This is the reason for the final `NULL`, which is happily ignored by `ggplot2`.

Another possible workaround is to write

```
plot <- ggplot(data, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_point() +
  #aes(alpha=0.3,color=scale) +
  #scale_color_gradient(high="red") +
  list()
```

The final `list()` is supposed to stay in place to cancel the effects of the last `+` sign; it is a no-op otherwise.

Comment: These are both helpful ways to avoid silly mistakes, thank you.

Answer (score 6):

With version 2.0.0, `ggplot2` has gained a new geometry, [`geom_blank()`](http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_blank.html) which draws nothing.

It can be used to avoid this type of errors when it is placed as last layer.

```
plot <- ggplot(data, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_point() +
  #aes(alpha=0.3,color=scale) +
  #scale_color_gradient(high="red") +
  geom_blank()
```

Using `geom_blank()` in this way is similar to the workaround in [@krlmlr's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21560594/3817004) which uses `list()` as last layer.