# add lines to an existing ggplot like generic line

Tags: r, ggplot2

I need to add some lines to an already drawn ggplot object. In the generic method we can use the function `lines` after the creation of a plot and the lines were added to this plot.
With `ggplot2`we theoricaly use the `geom_line()` argument in the same time as creating the `ggplot`object to add the lines. For example:

```
test_data <- data.frame(var0 = 100 + c(0, cumsum(runif(49, -20, 20))),
                        var1 = 150 + c(0, cumsum(runif(49, -10, 10))),
                        var3 = 1:100)
P1 <- ggplot(test_data, aes(var3)) + geom_line(aes(y = var0, colour = "var0")) +
                                     geom_line(aes(y = var1, colour = "var1"))
P1
```

But, In my case, I absolutly need to save the first plot in an object, to plot him, and to draw the lines in a second time (there are created by an other program with other data).

So, I can create three different object :

```
P1 <- ggplot(test_data, aes(var3))
L1 <- geom_line(aes(y = var0, colour = "var0"))
L2 <- geom_line(aes(y = var1, colour = "var1"))
```

and I can plot there :

```
P1 + L1 + L2
```

like if I plot P1 in generic method and use `lines` after (for L1 and L2).

But I don't know why I can't create this object where I add two lines and not one:

```
L3 <- L1 + L2
P1 + L3
```

I obtain this message:

> Error in L1 + L2 : non-numeric argument to binary operator.

I can't split the L3 object because it's create by only one function who return one object.

My question is how can I return the L3 object or an equivalant to add it at P1 after I had draw P1?

Comment: I think your real problem is in the first line of your question. I doubt that you must draw the plot before adding the line. I bet you can avoid that. If you can't, you could draw the lines using grid functions, e.g. `grid.lines`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is indeed doubt if you have to use this way, as pointed out by @Roland. However, the question remains: can we have something flexible like that? The answer is yes, we can, by using non-standard evaluation.

```
f <- function(x) {deparse(substitute(x))}
g <- function(x) {eval(parse(text=x))}
g(paste0(f(P1), " + ", f(L1))) # first line
g(paste0(f(P1), " + ", f(L2))) # second line
g(paste0(f(P1), " + ", f(L1 + L2))) # both lines
fL3 <- f(L1 + L2)
g(paste0(f(P1), " + ", fL3)) # both lines with defined variable
```

Why do we have to override standard evaluation of `+` operator within `ggplot`? Well, because we can add `geom` to `ggplot`, and the result is `ggplot` again. We cannot, however, add `geom` to `geom`, the result is undefined. We can probably add this functionality manually by wrapping the dirty hack above into something pretty, but that's not worth the effort, I suppose.

Edit: I think one more or less clean solution would be to define `+` operator for `proto` class, this should not break basic `ggplot` evaluation. Might worth a try.

Edit2: Actually, everything is *much, much simpler*, I'm overthinking (hint found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21560389/r-non-numeric-argument-to-binary-operator)):

```
P1 + list(L1, L2)
L3 <- list(L1, L2)
P1 + L3
```